# How to parse a filename into a timestamp?

Tags: linux, bash, date, parsing, filenames

So here is the filename i want to parse:
`file_name-19-02-17-21.03.02.tgz`

I am trying to parse the filename which has a time in it in to output a timeframe variable. How can I do that? I want to compare it to the current timestamp to get a difference.

And I am writing a bash script.

I expect a timestamp. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you please provide your sample input and expected output?

Answer (score -1):

eg:

```
echo file_name-19-02-17-21.03.02.tgz | awk '{t=mktime(gensub(/file_name-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{2})\.([0-9]{2})\.tgz/, "20\\1 \\2 \\3 \\4 \\5 \\6", "")); printf("timestamp: %d diff: %d\n",t, systime() - t);}'
```

result:

```
timestamp: 1550455382 diff: 3698
```